# Does glMapBufferRange wait for glBufferSubData with context resource sharing?

Tags: opengl-es

Assume that I'm currently uploading data to a vertex buffer using glBufferSubData or I currently have it mapped via glMapBufferRange in Thread A on Context A. Then I call glBufferSubData or glMapBufferRange on the same buffer in Thread B on Context B via context sharing.

Will the second call block until the upload in Thread A has finished / the buffer has been unmapped? Or do I have to track myself which thread/context currently maps or works on which buffer?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES does not provide any automatic synchronization for bulk data access across contexts (it has weak synchronization for state within a share group, but not data) so any synchronization must be handled externally.